# Possible to use Office add-in SSO without involving server in auth process?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm investigating using Single-Sign-On with Microsoft Graph for an Outlook Office-JS add-in that we deploy to customers. The add-in files are hosted on a central add-in service owned by us which all the different customer manifests reference.

In the Microsoft tutorials they mention creating a Client secret. From what I've seen in tutorials (the yeoman Office SSO generator for example) once the secret is created in Azure it needs to be passed on the call to retrieve an MS Graph **access token** using the initial bootstrap token that office-js obtains via the getAccessToken method.

In the yeoman generator example the secret is stored in Windows credentials, read at server startup and placed into an environment variable the server can access when a call from client to authenticate the add-in is made. For an add-in service used by multiple customers this would need to have access to multiple client secrets and use the correct one based on a key like client ID. The ability to access/manage such a store is not currently available with our add-in service, it has only been used for serving the add-in scripts so far.

Is it necessary to involve a server to participate in the SSO authentication process for MS Graph with Office add-ins? Can SSO to Microsoft Graph be achieved with solely client-side add-in code in a secure way?

- Writing the customer specific secret into each manifest would be a security flaw since then anyone with access to the manifest could copy the add-in authorization details and make use of our service's registration through their add-in also right? Though wouldn't the configured Application URI block this from being used by any service other than our add-in service with its FQDN?

Relevant Microsoft documentation

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/sso-quickstart
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.auth?view=excel-js-preview#getAccessToken_options_
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph

Answer (score 2):

You can use a purely client-side method, specifically the Implicit Flow, if you are willing to give up SSO and force your users to login the first time they access MS Graph, even if they are already logged into Office.

But if you want to use SSO, there's no way to avoid having a server because the bootstrap token you get with SSO has to be swapped using the On-Behalf-Of Flow, which is a server-side flow.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a technical limitation that limits the flow to server-side only? If I had the client secret available to my add-in client-side would the same flow fail to be invoked from the client e.g. due to CORS configuration?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by technical limitation. It is just built into the design of the On-Behalf-Of flow that it is a server-to-server flow.